# "'Student' is a namespace but is used like a type" error while declaring DbSet inside DbContext

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am trying to declare the `DbSet` property of my `StudentDbContext` using a class which has the same name as the namespace.

This is my `StudentDbContext` code

```
using Student.Web.Models;    
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Student.Web.StudentContext
{
    public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentDbContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The last line of the code, where I am trying to declare `DbSet<Student>` is throwing the error message:

> 'Student' is a namespace but is used like a type

This is my model with namespace

```
namespace Student.Web.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening. I have a model class that is called `Student`.

Does .Net Core handle namespaces differently?

Comment: No, but you likely didn't declare the namespace where your Students class is located at. You should post your students model including namespace

Comment: @tseng I dint get you sorry. But I did add the model file with namespace and showed how I have included it in my dbcontext. I am unable to figure out whats wrong. I don't know what I am missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a namespace and a class that is named Student. Not very good. To get around it you can prefix the class name with the namespace; like Student.Student. But the best idea it to rename the namespace I would say!

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/

Answer (score 2):

When you have conflicts between namespace & models, move the `using` statement inside the namespace declaration

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Student.Web.StudentContext
{
    // Move it here
    using Student.Web.Models;

    public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentDbContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace Student.Web.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When the compiler looks for the class it will first use the inner usings and when it doesn't find it, will search for the type in the outer usings.

This has always worked this way in C# and is nothing new with .NET Core.

The reason for this is, when you have the namespace of `Student.Web.StudentContext` you can access all types in `Student.Web.StudentContext`, `Student.Web` and `Student` without an `using` statement.

But in the scenario you have, the compiler doesn't know if you want to reference `Student` (the namespace) or `Student.Web.Models.Student` the class.

By moving the using declaration inside it can be fixed, because the compiler will find `Student` inside `Student.Web.Models` namespace and not look further up (and ending with `Student` namespace).